# Автоматический сброс кэша в Android

Tags: jquery, mobile, android, javascript

Приветствую Всех!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, делаю приложение на Jquery Mobile + Phonegap.

Получаю информацию, записываю в local storage, смотрю информацию о приложение данные записаны, а кеш растет через 2 часа работы приложения 5 мб кеш, как его можно сбрасывать автоматически?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я чищу кэш Android'а так:

```
void clearCache(Context context)
{
    clearCacheFolder(context.getCacheFolder());
}

void clearCacheFolder(final File dir) 
{      
    if (dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()) 
    {         
        try 
        {             
            for (File child:dir.listFiles()) 
            {                  
               //рекурсивно чистим сначала каталоги                 
                if (child.isDirectory()) 
                    clearCacheFolder(child);
                else //потом собственно файлы
                    child.delete(); 
            }         
        }         
        catch(Exception e) 
        {             
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to clean the cache error message="+e.getMessage());         
        }     
    }     
}
```